# Is there native touch listener in android?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

In java i can listen to native clicks using [NativeMouseListener](https://jnativehook.googlecode.com/svn/tags/javadoc-1.1/org/jnativehook/mouse/NativeMouseListener.html) from the global screen,
Is there any way to listen to native touches in android? 
means listen to touch from the other global activities

Comment: I don't think Android allows you to access what is going on in other apps for security reasons.  I could be wrong about that.

Comment: i just want detect native touches and no more heh

Comment: It's my understanding that unless you KNOW the package name, and have access to it, you cannot intercept anything that goes on in it.  Including where the user touches the screen.

Comment: You may look at [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html). See "Retrieving window content" section.

Comment: check also [motion event][1]
  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Comment: No - as  @durbnpoisn points out, ordinary apps can only access touch information from their *own* windows. If you want to access global touch data, your app requires signature level permissions (i.e be signed by the same key used when building the Android OS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving this in as an answer, as it has been confirmed by @adelphus in comments:

It's my understanding that unless you KNOW the package name, and have access to it, you cannot intercept anything that goes on in it. Including where the user touches the screen.